# Update huge Firebase database as a transaction

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase database for iOS application and maintain huge database. For some events I have use cloud functions to simultaneous updates of several siblings nodes as a transaction. However some nodes contains huge child nodes (may be one million). Is it worst expanding huge number of records in cloud function?

Comment: What do you mean by "expanding huge number of records"?  Can you give a more concrete example of how clients are interacting with your data?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does have a limit on the size of data it can GET and POST. Take a look at  the Data Tree of this site https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits

It mentions the max depth, and size limits of objects.

> Maximum depth of child nodes  32
>
> Maximum size of a string  10 MB

If your database has millions or records you should use the query parameters and limit your request to smaller sub sections of your data.

Comment: I'm talking about the cloud function.